# Cron job ubuntu on range hours

Tags: ubuntu, cron, job-scheduling

I need cron job to run every hour between 9am to 11 pm every days, i use ubuntu.
I try with:

```
    50 9  * * py script
    50 10  * * py script
    50 11  * * py script
    ...
    50 23  * * py script
```

its posible, only 1 line command?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run crom job at every 50 minute from 09:50 to 23:50, try this:

```
*/50 9-23 * * * /path/to/py /path/to/script
```

It will be executed *"At every 50th minute past every hour from 9 through 23."*

If you want to the cron job to be executed as a specific user, try this:

```
*/50 9-23 * * * username /path/to/py /path/to/script
```

This second version only works for `/etc/crontab` and cron files located in `/etc/cron.d/`.

Other possible combinations you can try at [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/50_9-23_*_*_*)